# Bootstrap file input by Krajee after upload file preview with icon disappears

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-file-input

The file preview disappears after uploading a file. The process uploads to a location not on the server where the site is hosted. The link to the uploaded document is not available after upload, but we are using icons instead of a preview of the file.

Specs:
ASPNET MVC C#,
Razor pages,
Targeting framework 4.6.1,

HTML markup

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">
        <label>Uploader configured via JS </label>
        <div class="file-loading">
            <input id="input-js" name="input-js[]" type="file" multiple>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

JS and fileinput config

```
 $('#input-js').fileinput({
            showUpload: true,

            previewFileType: 'image',
            dropZoneEnabled: true,
            browseOnZoneClick: true,
            uploadAsync: true,
            theme: 'fas',
            uploadUrl: "/Home/FileUpload",
            deleteUrl: "/Home/FileDelete",
            maxFileCount: 3, 
            maxFileSize: 240, 
            maxFilePreviewSize: 10240, 
            initialPreviewAsData: true,
            overwriteInitial: false,
            preferIconicPreview: true, 
            previewFileIconSettings: { 
                // configure your icon file extensions
                'doc': '<i class="fas fa-file-word text-primary"></i>',
                'xls': '<i class="fas fa-file-excel text-success"></i>',
                'ppt': '<i class="fas fa-file-powerpoint text-danger"></i>',
                'pdf': '<i class="fas fa-file-pdf text-danger"></i>',
                'zip': '<i class="fas fa-file-archive text-muted"></i>',
                'htm': '<i class="fas fa-file-code text-info"></i>',
                'txt': '<i class="fas fa-file-alt text-info"></i>',
                'mov': '<i class="fas fa-file-video text-warning"></i>',
                'mp3': '<i class="fas fa-file-audio text-warning"></i>',
                // note for these file types below no extension determination logic
                // has been configured (the keys itself will be used as extensions)
                'jpg': '<i class="fas fa-file-image text-danger"></i>',
                'gif': '<i class="fas fa-file-image text-muted"></i>',
                'png': '<i class="fas fa-file-image text-primary"></i>'
            },
            previewFileExtSettings: { // configure the logic for determining icon file extensions
                'doc': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(doc|docx)$/i);
                },
                'xls': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(xls|xlsx)$/i);
                },
                'ppt': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(ppt|pptx)$/i);
                },
                'zip': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(zip|rar|tar|gzip|gz|7z)$/i);
                },
                'htm': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(htm|html)$/i);
                },
                'txt': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(txt|ini|csv|java|php|js|css)$/i);
                },
                'mov': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(avi|mpg|mkv|mov|mp4|3gp|webm|wmv)$/i);
                },
                'mp3': function (ext) {
                    return ext.match(/(mp3|wav)$/i);
                }
            }
        });
```

Json returned from upload

```
initialPreview: "/Content/greencheckmark.jpg"
initialPreviewAsData: true
initialPreviewConfig: Array(1)
0:
key: "a9483866-251c-4be2-aa49-6f0b5088434d"
caption: "Gas Heating.pdf"
size: 183294
fileId: "a9483866-251c-4be2-aa49-6f0b5088434d"
url: "/Home/FileDelete"
extra:
fileName: "Gas Heating.pdf"
spId: "a9483866-251c-4be2-aa49-6f0b5088434d"
__proto__: Object
type: "pdf"
filetype: "application/pdf"
```

The JSON response is built per document, 'initialPreviewConfig' is different per document but always with a single value in the array.  'initialPreview' and 'initialPreviewAsData' are the same for all documents.

When a single file is uploaded nothing shows in the preview. When 3 files are uploaded; 2 return correctly one returns a preview with no information [view snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tt5E.png).

I am lost on what is wrong or why the behavior is inconsistent.

Thank you in advance for assisting with this issue.